# how to declare in data class an object inside of another object from json?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm getting the next trouble declaring my models on android

I have this api response:

```
 {
    "isWeekTopic": false,
    "_id": "62d739f65a4f2db1b81b5192",
    "topicNumber": "1",
    "title": "Números naturales",
    "thumbnail": "https://www.example.com",
    "relatedSkillsId": [
        "62c12752d9de3e63d7cd0a78"
    ],
    "relatedSubSkillsId": [
        "62d73a8c5a4f2db1b81b5194"
    ],
    "createdAt": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "testing": {
        "mainColor": "#f2f2f2",
        "secondColor": "#f2f2f2",
        "image": "https://www.example.com"
    },
    "assetsStreak": {
        "VIDEO": 2,
        "STORY": 0,
        "VIDEOGAME": 2,
        "INFOGRAPHIC": 2,
        "EXPLANATION": 0,
        "STEPBYSTEP": 2
    },
    "skillPercent": 60
}
```

and this is my remote response model:

```
    data class TopicsItemRemoteResponseModel(
    @field:SerializedName("_id")
    val topicsId: String = "",
    @field:SerializedName("title")
    val title: String = "",
    @field:SerializedName("skillNumber")
    val skillNumber: Int = 0,
    @field:SerializedName("skillPercent")
    val skillPercent: Int = 0,
    @field:SerializedName("thumbnail")
    val thumbnail: String = "",
    @field:SerializedName("createdAt")
    val createdAt: String = "",
    @field:SerializedName("updatedAt")
    val updatedAt: String = "",
    @field:SerializedName("isWeekTopic")
    val isWeekTopic: Boolean = false,
    @field:SerializedName("relatedSkillsId")
    val relatedSkillsId: List<String> = listOf(),
    @field:SerializedName("relatedSubSkillsId")
    val relatedSubSkillsId: List<String> = listOf(),


) : Parcelable {
    companion object {
        fun mapListFromRemoteToDomainModel(
            remoteList: List<TopicsItemRemoteResponseModel>): List<TopicsItemResponseModel> {
            val topics = mutableListOf<TopicsItemResponseModel>()
            remoteList.forEach { topicsRemoteResponseItem ->
                topics.add(
                    mapFromRemoteToDomainModel(topicsRemoteResponseItem)
                )
            }
            return topics
        }
        private fun mapFromRemoteToDomainModel(
            topicsRemoteResponseItem: TopicsItemRemoteResponseModel
        ): TopicsItemResponseModel = with(topicsRemoteResponseItem) {
            return TopicsItemResponseModel(
                topicsId = topicsId,
                skillNumber = skillNumber,
                title = title,
                skillPercent = skillPercent,
                thumbnail = thumbnail,
                createdAt = createdAt,
                updatedAt = updatedAt,
                isWeekTopic = isWeekTopic,
                relatedSkillsId = relatedSkillsId,
                relatedSubSkillsId = relatedSubSkillsId,
           
            )
        }
    }
}
```

my problem is that I don't know how to access to assetsStreak info or testing info, I don't know how to declare them o what to do.
I tied doing something like putting declaring it this way

@field:SerializedName("assetsStreak")
val assetsStreak: assetsStreak,

but android studio tellsme its an error: unresolved reference: assetsStreak

I'm trying to learn kotlin, but there is no info about this case that I could find, please I'm desperate
thanks for you time

so after declared the class AssetStreak it doesn't mark error anymore but the problem goes to the response model which I made it this way

```
@Parcelize
data class TopicsItemResponseModel(
    val topicsId: String = "",
    val title: String = "",
    val skillNumber: Int = 0,
    val thumbnail: String ="",
    val createdAt: String = "",
    val updatedAt: String = "",
    val relatedSubSkillsId: List<String> = listOf(),
    val relatedSkillsId: List<String> = listOf(),
    val skillPercent: Int = 10,
    val isWeekTopic: Boolean = false,
    val assetsStreak: assetsStreak,

) : Parcelable {}
```

this way the error says unresolved reference asstsStreak and give me the option to create a class

if I put val assetsStreak: AssetsStreak,
this way the error says unresolved reference AssetsStreakand give me the option to add dependency on another module should i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a class named **a**ssetStreak? (notice it starts with a lowercase a)

The second line of this

```
 @field:SerializedName("title")
    val title: String = "",
```

seems to be saying, give me a value of something called title which will be a String object.
So I'm guessing that if you define a class **A**ssetsStreak (the A is capital by convention) then this will work

```
@field:SerializedName("assetsStreak") 
val assetsStreak: AssetsStreak,
```

Psuedo code for AssetsStreak class

```
class AssetsStreak {
  val video: String,
  val story: String,
  val videoGame: String,
 ...
},
```

Comment: yeah this works on the remote response Model but it makes error on the response model , gonna edit to show the error

Answer (score 0):

You can parce the response in the following way.

```
@Parcelize
data class TopicsItemRemoteModel(
   val _id: String,
   val assetsStreak: AssetsStreak,
   val createdAt: String,
   val isWeekTopic: Boolean,
   val relatedSkillsId: List<String>,
   val relatedSubSkillsId: List<String>,
   val skillPercent: Int,
   val testing: Testing,
   val thumbnail: String,
   val title: String,
   val topicNumber: String,
   val updatedAt: String
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class AssetsStreak(
   val EXPLANATION: Int,
   val INFOGRAPHIC: Int,
   val STEPBYSTEP: Int,
   val STORY: Int,
   val VIDEO: Int,
   val VIDEOGAME: Int
) : Parcelable


@Parcelize
data class Testing(
   val image: String,
   val mainColor: String,
   val secondColor: String
) : Parcelable
```

Comment: when i try this it gives me an error on the mapFromRemoteToDomainModel function.
if i put  assetsStreak = assetsStreak, it says something about not having a companion object?

Comment: then, you can create a companion object like the above as you have done.